# Microsoft Office 2016 fails to install with errors 1603, FC73469E

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2016

I am attempting to install Microsoft Office 2016 Pro Plus (classic, not click-to-run)

The installation fails, here is an excerpt from Windows Event Viewer:

```
Fault bucket 124669380009, type 5
Event Name: OfficeClassicSetup
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0
Problem signature:

P1: 16.0.4266.1001
P2: OSETUP.DLL
P3: 16.0.4266.1001
P4: 1603
P5: Unspecified
P6: FC73469E
P7: 1603
P8: 
P9: 
P10:
```

Looking through the event log, I found this line:

```
'CAInstallLicenses:  Error: Failed to install license. HResult: 0x80070005. '
```

Following it, there are many variations of this error with a bunch of DLLs:

```
'07/19/2016 12:57:45.679 [2300]: Assembly Install: Failing with hr=80070005 at RemoveDirectoryAndChildren, line 384
'
2016/07/19 12:57:45:679::[2780] MSI(INFO): '07/19/2016 12:57:45.679 [2300]: Detailed info about C:\WINDOWS\assembly\tmp\XKNCYCIC\OFFICE.DLL
'
```

Error 80070005 appears to be a permissions related issue.  I have verified that SYSTEM has full control of `C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Office` (though not the parent folder) and `C:\WINDOWS\assembly`.

- I am running as administrator
- I have tried this with a "clean boot" so hopefully there's no antivirus blocking anything
- I am installing Microsoft Office 2016 Pro Plus 32-bit
- I am running Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit

Can anyone help with this error?  I can post the full installation log upon request.

Comment: Google gives you nothing ? Maybe tech support ?

Comment: I've tried Google.  All the results are about Office 2013, not 2016.  I tried many of those solutions anyway, many were not applicable, the ones that were (like clean boot) did nothing.

Comment: Are you trying to install a pirated version? if yes that's probably the issue, as pirated apps often are modified with stuff removed. If you actually paid for it and can't install it, it's clearly an issue for MS tech support.

Comment: It's definitely not pirated.  I'll try going to MS tech support, but they're typically a lot less competent than the people on Stackexchange.  If it gets resolved I'll make sure to come back and self-answer.

Comment: Hey @Mystagogue did you ever work out this issue? I'm seeing something very similar. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrew No, unfortunately.  I ended up installing them from a different source and it seemed to work okay, though.